# javascript comma separators and session storage

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, sessionstorage

I'm new to javascript and so I don't fully understand passing objects... my final product is simple build a comma separated counter that doesn't reset when someone refreshes the page.  Guymid build a jsbin demo http://jsbin.com/IyavAPoN/1/edit. It seems that the solution to my problem is pretty straightforward but I can't seem to put them together.

to not reset, someone suggested using sessionStorage which seem to work on another code but I can't seem to incorporate it to the codes that I have as reflected in the JSBin Link.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your attempt here. We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't show your code.

Comment: What's a _comma separated counter_?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/IyavAPoN/1/edit shows exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: just a comma separated value.  The value is a counter.  If you follow the link, it just increments by a certain number.

Comment: Code has to go in the question, not in a pastebin link. This is off-topic and should be closed unless the code is edited in.

Comment: Can you post the code where you tried to use `sessionStorage`?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/AfOHixu/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is simply do localStorage: http://jsbin.com/ogeYOZa/2/ i basically just store values in localStorage and that's the only difference. However, there are a few more: Instead of just using `+=1` to increment values, I use `parseInt` because localStorage values are strings.